# CSS z-index/heignt:auto not compatible

Tags: css, angular, typescript, quill

I have imported the Quill editor component into my project Angular,

This is the html:

```
<form [ngFormGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
class="form">
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!content.valid
&& content.touched), 'has-success': (content.valid
&& content.touched)}">
  <quill-editor class="form-control" [ngFormControl]="content [options]="editorConfig"></quill-editor>
</div>
</form>
```

And the css:

```
.form-control {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.ql-tooltip {
  z-index: 1100;
}
```

At first, i got this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIAVW.png)
Then with height:auto, i got this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiGJI.png)
A part of the toolbar is lost.
And the z-index doesn't work at all.

I want to get a text editor panel's height auto resized, and display the complet toolbar like here: 
[enter link description here](https://surmon-china.github.io/ngx-quill-editor/)

Thank you

Comment: `z-index` has no effect on elements unless they have a position value that is NOT `static`.

Comment: ..and `z-index` and `height` are not related.

Comment: Consider declaring a `z-index` property on the containing element `.form-control` - it doesn't look like `.form-control` is *positioned* either, so declare `position: relative` in addition so that the `z-index` property may apply.

Comment: i tried these possibilities, not work.   this is what i want: https://surmon-china.github.io/ngx-quill-editor/